# How to copy code change in git from 1 file to another

Tags: git

I am new to Git and was exploring a possibility. My requirement was

> 1) If a made a change to a file in a git repository, how can I automatically copy and commit the changes in another file in the same repository.

*Example*

There is an SQL file, this is the main SQL file, and there is an `upgrade.sql` file. If I made any changes in `main.sql`, how can I copy the changes in `update.sql` file?

Comment: Are these repo related at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use git hooks. 
If you want to copy main.sql in upgrade.sql as it is then you can force copy main.sql as upgrade.sql.
You have to perform following steps:

1. Rename sample pre-commit git hook :

```
mv .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

2. Open .git/hooks/pre-commit to edit :

```
vi .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

3. Add copy script in pre-commit file. This step will overwrite upgrade.sql always (so if you have other logic like updating only few line etc then modify script according to your requirements) :

```
cp main.sql upgrade.sql
```

4. commit the change

```
git commit -a -m "my change"
```

There are different hooks available similar to pre-commit. You can choose based on your requirement. Here is more information on git-hooks :
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

I hope it helps.